# como contar numero de elementos input file do html com php?

Tags: php, html, file-upload, input

preciso contar o numero de elementos input file, pois são criados dinamicamente, com o clique de um botão

```
  <input class="tf" type="file" name="pic[]" accept="image/*">
```

essa é a linha que é criada dinamicamente, mas preciso contar o numero de elementos que foram criados, não dá certo com o count, como posso fazer?

esse é meu código php, com a variavel paragrafo ja da certo.

```
  <?php

$paragrafo  = isset($_POST['paragrafo']) ? $_POST['paragrafo'] : '';

$foto = isset($_FILES['pic']) ? $_FILES['pic'] : '' ;

echo count($_POST['pic']);

if(count($paragrafo) > 0 && $paragrafo != ''){
    foreach($paragrafo as $item){
        echo  $item .'<br>';
    }
} else {
    echo "Nenhum paragrafo foi adicionado!";
}
```

?>

Comment: Isto é um _input file_ normalmente retorna uma array simples, para um único ficheiro selecionado, e retorna uma multi. quando definido _multiple_. O que se pretende ao certo é ?

Comment: eu quero contar o numero de inputs que foram criados no meu html

Comment: Os campos são gerados via _php_ ?

Comment: não, via plugin jquery/javascript

Comment: Mas o _input_ do tipo _file_ normalmente é um só.

Comment: conforme o clique do botão adicionar imagem,  com id="add-img"

Comment: é que terei que gerar um documento pdf, e esse terá que ter imagens e paragrafos, tendo necessariamente que ter a ordem que estaria apresentada na tela, dentre paragrafos e imagens...

Comment: Eu, para não ter que pensar muito, adicionaria na função JS que adiciona os imagens uma chamada a outra função que incrementa um valor numérico em um campo oculto. toda vez que adicionar vc teria o valor exato dos campos no seu DOM

Answer (score -1):

se esse é seu input $_FILES['pic'] então você só tem **um** input, caso queira contar as imagens dentro dele faz um `sizeof($_FILES['pic'])` e se quiser percorrer as imagens faz um `foreach($_FILES['pic'] as $file){ }`

Comment: é que crio dinamicamente, com o mesmo name, varios inputs, mas vo tentar assim, como vc disse